# Exit Python Module WIthout Exiting PyDev Console

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) on MacOS 10.12.3 and PyDev 5.5.0.201701191708.  I have a few subroutines in the module I'm working on that will need to exit to the command line when I run this script in bash.  I use sys.exit(0), but have also used exit(0).  When I test this module in the PyDev console, these statements exit the console as well as the module.

How can I quit the module without quitting the console?  While I can use a return statement in debugging, when I'm done and this is being run from the command line, I want program execution to stop at these points and exit back to the command line.

Comment: take a look at the `pdb` debugging package... something like `pdb.set_trace()` I think ... pycharm has a built in debugger , you can just place breakpoints and open a console at any of the breakpoints... I would assume eclipse offers something simillar

Answer (score 1):

I must say it's a bit hard to know what exactly you want from your description...

So, I'll give you some choices:

1. You can use the interactive console to call each of your functions (http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html) -- note that you can even start it under the debugger to see locals, have breakpoints, etc (http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html#full-debug-support-in-interactive-console).
2. Just run it under the debugger and put breakpoints where you want.(http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_debugger.html)
3. Actually structure your code the way you said (although I find it a bit strange... can you give more details on what exactly you'd want to achieve and why you want that workflow?)

Comment: I often exit a Python script with sys.exit(0).  Using this in the PyDev console means it exits not just my program but the console as well.  So what commands can I use to terminate the script that's running without exiting the console?

Comment: Well, that's actually expected... I'm not sure you can exit like you want though (anything you execute would be in the context of the break in the console, not change your actual program flow) -- what you want is probably making it raise an exception of a given kind which is handled at a proper place for that... I think that you can try to interrupt the process (the yellow button) which should raise a ctrl+c to the program to do what you want (you may have to handle that at your own program to prevent it from exiting thought).